# Beanstalk queue Error [PDOException] could not find driver. when save database eloquent

Tags: laravel, queue, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

Hei guys i got an error "Error [PDOException] could not find driver" like describe on my title. anyone know how to fixed it ??

this is my .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:CZRXQSmW+gkqzEV0NzRZDtxmsUjoHdk3ZuYqkIh3rgw=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=secret
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

and there is my code

this one is queue one

```
namespace Automation\Jobs;

use Automation\Models\UserLog;
use Automation\Models\User;
use Automation\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;


class SendReminderEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($id)
    {

      $this->user = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo "start";

        $userlog = new UserLog;
        $userlog->email = $this->user."@test.com";
        $userlog->admin = $this->user;
        $userlog->description = $this->user;
        $userlog->created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $userlog->save();

        $sleep = mt_rand(1, 10);
        sleep($sleep);

        $userlog = new UserLog;
        $userlog->email = $this->user."@test.com";
        $userlog->admin = $this->user;
        $userlog->description = $this->user;
        $userlog->created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $userlog->save();

        echo "end";
    }
}
```

and i just call with function like this

```
$this->dispatch(new SendReminderEmail(7));
```

i worked on ubuntu server and the error appears when im using php artisan queue:listen on command line

Comment: Please post your `.env` file and code which you use to save data.

Comment: already edit at my question @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: I bet you have wrong DB configuration. Do you use Homestead?

Comment: @alexeymezenin no im not using,  it can works or create record on another controller that not implements queue

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no im not using, it can works or create record on another controller that not implements queue

Answer (score 0):

this happens because im not installed sql on linux.
In linux terminal: sudo apt-get install php5-mysql and that problem gone